# How can I upload multiple images with md5 name using php?

Tags: php, md5

```
<?php
include"db.php";
if(isset($_POST['btn_upload']))
{
 $v1=rand(1111,9999);
 $v2=rand(1111,9999);
 $v3=$v1.$v2;
 $v3=md5($v3);

for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES["file_img"]["name"]); $i++ )
 {
  //select folder id to insert all images
   $folder_name=$_POST['select_folder_name'];


    $filename=$_FILES["file_img"]["name"][$i];
    $filetype=$_FILES["file_img"]["type"][$i];
    $gallery_image_dst="./gallery_image/".$v3.$filename;
    $gallery_image_location="gallery_image/".$v3.$filename;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"],$gallery_image_dst);

  //insert image name, path, type and folder name to database.
  $insert_gallery= "INSERT INTO `gallery`(`image_name`, `image_path`, 
  `image_type`,`folder_name`) VALUES 
  ('$filename','$gallery_image_location','$filetype','$folder_name')";

   $result=mysqli_query($conn, $insert_gallery);         
   if($result){
        echo"<script>alert('Successfully uploaded')</script>";
        echo"<script>window.open('index.php?upload_images','_self') 
        </script>";
   }else{
       echo"<script>alert('Oop! Somthing going wrong')</script>";
   }  
  } 
 }
?>
```

Here I am getting all image location, image type, and image md5 name in my database. But problem is that I'm not getting any images to my gallery_image folder. After Successfully uploaded message I'm getting a error Warning:move_upload_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in c"\xampp........location and line no.

Comment: Depending on your use case it may be better to hash the file contents rather then the name, as an added bonus you will be able to tell if the same file is uploaded multiple times, because it's contents should hash out the same, this is what I typically do, but I usually prefix it with a user ID  `userID-hash` that way it's unique per user, Or I store all the users images in a Zip file then provide them via output stream right from the zip, it works pretty awesome that way.

Answer (score 2):

you missed index [$i]

You have to update,

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"][$i],$gallery_image_dst);
```

Comment: after adding move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"][$i],$gallery_image_dst); I am getting failed to open stream error. Please find the attached screenshot.

Comment: that means your $gallery_image_dst path is wrong. Can you show your folder file structure where is your this file upload code file and where is the folder in which you want to upload file?

Comment: Thank you,now it is working. File path was wrong it should be gallery_images.